# Making a filter for a List - ANDROID

Tags: java, android, list, mobile

I'm facing a problem while developing my Android app:

I have a List, that saves custom objects:

```
public class Centro implements Serializable {
    String id;
    String nombre;
    String direccion;
    Boolean infantil;
    Boolean primaria;
    Boolean eso;
    Boolean bachillerato;
    Boolean fp;
    Boolean universidad;
    String descripcion;
    Provincia province;

    public Centro(String id, String nombre,
            String direccion, Boolean infantil,
            Boolean primaria, Boolean eso,
            Boolean bachillerato, Boolean fp,
            Boolean universidad, String descripcion,
            Provincia province) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.infantil = infantil;
        this.primaria = primaria;
        this.eso = eso;
        this.bachillerato = bachillerato;
        this.fp = fp;
        this.universidad = universidad;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.province = province;
    }
}
```

In my activity, when the values of getBachillerato, getUniversidad and getFp are false, I want to add that object to another list. The issue is that when I make the filter, and I use an adapter to show the list in a ListView, it doesn't show anything, it is like if there were nothing in the list, like if any object passed the filter.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle {

    private static String url = "https://testapi-pprog2.azurewebsites.net/api/schools.php?method=getSchools";
    ListView listView;
    List<Centro> centroListaOne = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context ctx;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new cargarCentrosLista().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        listView = v.findViewById(R.id.listViewOne);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragment() {
        new cargarCentrosLista().execute();
    }

    private class cargarCentrosLista extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        List<Centro> list = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray heroArray = obj.getJSONArray("msg");
                    for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject centroObjeto = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Centro centro = new Centro();
                        centro.setNombre(centroObjeto.getString("schoolName"));
                        centro.setDireccion(centroObjeto.getString("schoolAddress"));
                        centro.setId(centroObjeto.getString("id"));
                        if (centroObjeto.getString("isBatxillerat") == "0") {
                            centro.setBachillerato(false);
                        } else {
                            centro.setBachillerato(true);
                        }
                        if (centroObjeto.getString("isEso") == "0") {
                            centro.setEso(false);
                        } else {
                            centro.setBachillerato(true);
                        }
                        if (centroObjeto.getString("isBatxillerat") == "0") {
                            centro.setBachillerato(false);
                        } else {
                            centro.setBachillerato(true);
                        }
                        if (centroObjeto.getString("isFP") == "0") {
                            centro.setFp(false);
                        } else {
                            centro.setFp(true);
                        }
                        if (centroObjeto.getString("isInfantil") == "0") {
                            centro.setInfantil(false);
                        } else {
                            centro.setInfantil(true);
                        }
                        if (centroObjeto.getString("isPrimaria") == "0") {
                            centro.setPrimaria(false);
                        } else {
                            centro.setPrimaria(true);
                        }
                        if (centroObjeto.getString("isUniversitat") == "0") {
                            centro.setUniversidad(false);
                        } else {
                            centro.setUniversidad(true);
                        }
                        switch (centroObjeto.getString("province")) {
                            case "barcelona":
                                centro.setProvince(Provincia.BARCELONA);
                                break;
                            case "girona":
                                centro.setProvince(Provincia.GIRONA);
                                break;
                            case "lleida":
                                centro.setProvince(Provincia.LLEIDA);
                                break;
                            case "tarragona":
                                centro.setProvince(Provincia.TARRAGONA);
                                break;
                            default:
                                centro.setProvince(null);
                                break;
                        }
                        centroListaOne.add(centro);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {

                }
            } else {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            List<Centro> listaFiltro = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Centro centro : centroListaOne){
                if(centro.getBachillerato() == false
                        && centro.getUniversidad() == false
                        && centro.getFp() == false){
                    listaFiltro.add(centro);
                }
            }
            CentroAdapter adapter = new CentroAdapter(listaFiltro, getActivity());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

My adapter:

```
public class CentroAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Centro> implements Filterable {

private List<Centro> heroList;
private Context mCtx;

public CentroAdapter(List<Centro> heroList, Context mCtx) {
    super(mCtx, R.layout.mockup_lista_escuela, heroList);
    this.heroList = heroList;
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mockup_lista_escuela, null, true);
    TextView nombre = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.nombreEscuela);
    TextView direcciom = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.direccionEscuela);
    ImageView imagen = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imagenEscuela);
    Centro hero = heroList.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load("https://fotos00.diarioinformacion.com/2010/09/14/318x200/2010-09-21_IMG_2010-09-14_01.31.35__M0701BENIDORM.jpg.jpg").into(imagen);
    nombre.setText(hero.getNombre());
    direcciom.setText(hero.getDireccion());

    return listViewItem;
}
```

}

EDIT: When I see how many items are in the new list, there are no items, basically any object pass the filter.

Comment: Please share your adapter class as well, and also have you debug and check how many centro items are there after filter ?

Comment: I just added the adapter

Comment: have you debug and check, is there are some item available after filter ??

Comment: No, there are no items added to the list after the filter

Comment: just confirming that before you set `adapter`, is there any items added in `listaFiltro` arraylist ?

Comment: No, after I set adapter, there is no item added in listaFiltro arraylist

Comment: check if your `centroListaOne` is empty? add `e.printStackTrace();` in your JSONException block to check if there is any parsing issue